# IDEA deploy a war as a directory on Jetty

Tags: intellij-idea, jetty, war

I'm trying to develope a Single Page App (Spring Web Mvc on the back-end + AngularJs on the front-end) on a Maven project in Intellij IDEA ULTIMATE 14.0.1. 
But when I deploy the war on Jetty 9.2.4. It display the war as a directory.
like this :
[image]